# debug a service after boot

Tags: android, debugging, service, boot

I need to debug a service after boot. The problem I have is that I don't see the debugger after calling

```
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

If I open the application through the debugger all works fine so I need the service to start running after boot and then to attach the debugger.

Thanks,

Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`waitForDebugger` freezes your app and waits for debbuger to be connected. You should open your IDE find your process and connect to it with a debugger (also you should set a break point if you need before connecting). Debugger wont connect by itself.
google 'android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger()'

Comment: When you say "connect to it with debugger" do you mean to Run->Debug->MyApp ?

Comment: In android studio there is an option 'Run->Attach debugger to android process'. If you choose Run->Debug it will kill your current process and start new one with a debugger. You need connect debugger to a process which is already running.

Comment: Eventually, I was able to connect via RUN->Debug.
 I don't see the Run->Attach option in Eclipse